Electronjs screenshot in ubuntu
Hi recently i am working on ElectronJs project and the functionality is to capture screenshot using desktop capturer but in window & mac it is working fine but in ubuntu whenever the screenshot capture it need share screen prompt. How can i avoid it in ubuntu as well from electronJs code
This is the electronJs code for screenshot capture
const sources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['screen'] });
const source = sources[0];  /

How to avoid share screen prompt in ubuntu to capture screenshot.
